# LISP function to make all possible pairs from a list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to create a LISP function that creates from a list all possible pairs.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve: (a b c d) --> ((a b) (a c) (a d) (b c) (b d) (c d))

Any advice please? I'm not sure how to approach this problem

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution:

```
(defun make-couples (x l)
  "makes a list of couples whose first element is x and the second is each element of l in turn"
  (loop for y in l collect (list x y)))

(defun all-pairs (l)
  "makes a list of all the possible pairs of elements of list l"
  (loop for (x . y) on l nconc (make-couples x y)))
```

A recursive solution is:

```
(defun make-couples (x l)
  "makes a list of couples whose first element is x and the second is each element of l in turn"
  (if (null l)
      nil
      (cons (cons x (first l)) (make-couples x (rest l)))))

(defun all-pairs (l)
  "makes a list of all the possible pairs of elements of list l"
  (if (null l)
      nil
      (nconc (make-couples (first l) (rest l))
             (all-pairs (rest l)))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how we could also solve this recursively ( without making a for loop?)

Answer (score 1):

Tail call recursive solution:

```
(defun pairs (lst &key (acc '()))
  (if (null (cdr lst))
      (nreverse acc)
      (pairs (cdr lst)
             :acc (append (nreverse
                           (mapcar #'(lambda (el) 
                                       (list (car lst) el)) 
                                   (cdr lst)))
                          acc))))
```

Both `nreverse`s are there just for aesthetics (for a nicer looking output). They can be left out.

Try it with:

```
(pairs '(a b c d))
;; => ((A B) (A C) (A D) (B C) (B D) (C D))
```

#### General Combinations

```
(defun pair (el lst)
  "Pair el with each element of lst."
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (cons el x)) lst))

(defun dedup (lst &key (test #'eql))
  "Deduplicate a list of lists by ignoring order 
   and comparing the elements by test function."
  (remove-duplicates lst :test (lambda (x y) (null (set-difference x y :test test)))))
  

(defun comb (lst &key (k 3) (acc '()) (test #'eql))
  "Return all unique k-mer combinations of the elements in lst."
  (labels ((%comb (lst &key (k k) (acc '()) (test #'eql) (total lst))
             (let ((total (if total total lst)))
               (cond ((or (null (cdr lst)) (zerop k)) (nreverse acc))
                     ((= k 1) (mapcar #'list lst))
                     (t (let* ((el (car lst))
                               (rst (remove-if (lambda (x) (funcall test x el)) total)))
                          (dedup (%comb (cdr lst)
                                       :k k
                                       :total total
                                       :test test
                                       :acc (append (pair el (comb rst :k (1- k) :test test))
                                                    acc)))))))))
    (%comb lst :k k :acc acc :test test :total lst)))
```

The number of combinations are calculatable with the combinations formula:

```
(defun fac (n &key (acc 1) (stop 1))
  "n!/stop!"
  (if (or (= n stop) (zerop n))
      acc
      (fac (1- n) :acc (* acc n) :stop stop)))

(defun cnr (n r)
  "Number of all r-mer combinations given n elements.
   nCr with n and r given"
  (/ (fac n :stop r) (fac (- n r))))
```

We can test and count:

```
(comb '(a b c d) :k 2)
;; => ((A D) (B D) (B A) (C D) (C B) (C A))

(comb '(a b c d e f) :k 3)
;; => ((B A F) (C B A) (C B F) (C A F) (D C A) (D C B) 
;; =>  (D C F) (D B A) (D B F) (D A F) (E D A) (E D B) 
;; =>  (E D C) (E D F) (E C A) (E C B) (E C F) (E B A)
;; =>  (E B F) (E A F))

(= (length (comb '(a b c d e f) :k 3)) (cnr 6 3)) ;; => T
(= (length (comb '(a b c d e f g h i) :k 6)) (cnr 9 6)) ;; => T
```

Comment: I might be confused, but this doesn't seem to get all possible combinations. Eg (A B D)

Comment: @Halbert Thank you for pointing out. I made the simpler version and replaced the wrong code.

Comment: @Halber added corrected `comb`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version (this is quite closely related to Gwang-Jin Kim's) which has two nice properties:

- it is tail recursive;
- it walks no list more than once;
- it allocates no storage that it does not use (so there are no calls to `append` and so on);
- it uses no destructive operations.

It does this by noticing that there's a stage in the process where you want to say 'prepend a list of pairs of this element with the elements of this list to this other list' and that this can be done without using `append` or anything like that.

It does return the results in 'reversed' order, which I believe is inevitable given the above constraints.

```
(defun all-pairs (l)
  (all-pairs-loop l '()))

(defun all-pairs-loop (l results)
  (if (null (rest l))
      results
    (all-pairs-loop (rest l)
                    (prepend-pairs-to (first l) (rest l) results))))

(defun prepend-pairs-to (e them results)
  (if (null them)
      results
    (prepend-pairs-to e (rest them) (cons (list e (first them))
                                    results))))
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest tail recursive variant without explicit loops / mapcar could also look like this:

```
(defun pairs (data)
  (labels ((rec (ls a bs res)
             (cond
               ((null ls) (nreverse res))
               ((null bs) (rec
                           (cdr ls)                               
                           (car ls)                                
                           (cdr ls)
                           res))
               (t (rec
                   ls
                   a
                   (cdr bs)                       
                   (cons (cons a (car bs)) res))))))
    (rec data nil nil nil)))

CL-USER> (pairs (list 1 2 3 4))
;; ((1 . 2) (1 . 3) (1 . 4) (2 . 3) (2 . 4) (3 . 4))
```